# RSpec test won't pass. Validating for uniqueness with domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.2.2.

I have a 'domain' model (domain.rb):

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :url
  belongs_to :user

  VALID_DOMAIN_REGEX = /^[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i
  validates :url, presence:true,
              format: { with: VALID_DOMAIN_REGEX },
              uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

end
```

And a test asserting that a duplicate domain should not be valid:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Domain do

  before do
    @domain = FactoryGirl.create(:domain)
  end

  subject { @domain }

  describe "when domain url is already taken" do
    before do
      domain_with_same_url = @domain.dup
      domain_with_same_url.url = @domain.url.upcase
      domain_with_same_url.save
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

The test keeps failing:

> 1) Domain when domain url is already taken 
>        Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
>          expected valid? to return false, got true
>        # ./spec/models/domain_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@domain is already created, validated and saved.

The `domain_with_same_url` is the new record, and it should be invalid. But you are not checking it.

Try

```
domain_with_same_url = FactoryGirl.create(:domain, :url => @domain.url.upcase)
domain_with_same_url.should_not be_valid
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Realize now I was conceptually missing a big item :) Should help me going forward with this testing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your two `before` blocks are run in outer-to inner order. Thus, when running your testsuite, first your `@domain` object gets created and saved, then the inner `before` block gets executed. Hiwever, your `domain_with_same_url` probably gets never actually saved because it's validation fails which probably leats to `domain_with_same_url.save` to return false.

As a workaround, you could check the validity of `domain_with_same_url` instead of `@domain`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `subject` of your test case is `@domain`, which is a valid object. Whether use new subject for `@domain_with_same_url` (don't forget to make it an instance variable), or explicitly say `domain_with_same_url.should ...` (just like The Who indicated in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem in [Rails 4 Model column uniqueness not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008551/rails-4-model-column-uniqueness-not-working).  It provides two other solutions without a second call to FactoryGirl, just FYI.  The one I am using is:

```
before(:each) do
  @feed_with_same_url = @feed.dup
  @feed_with_same_url.feed_url = @feed.feed_url
end
it { @feed_with_same_url.should_not be_valid }
```

The save is causing some problem, unexpected to me.  And, you need to reference an object to should_not_be_valid as a local variable.