# Rails 4 Model column uniqueness not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

This should be simple but I cannot figure out why it doesn't work. I have seen many more complex uniqueness constructs here.  I have column that should be a unique index.  I have specified it twice in the model, just testing options, but my test for uniqueness continues to fail.

Model validation code:

```
  validates :feed_url,    presence:true,
            format:     {with: VALID_URL_REGEX},
            uniqueness: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :feed_url
```

RSpec code:

```
  before do
    @feed = FactoryGirl.create(:feed)
  end
...

  describe "when URL is already taken" do
    before do
      feed_with_same_url = @feed.dup
      feed_with_same_url.feed_url = @feed.feed_url
      feed_with_same_url.save
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

The save should not be valid but the tests fails because the model says it is valid even though the fields are equal.  I have checked the fields myself at a breakpoint and they are exactly the same in case, length, value, etc.

Tests for presence and Regex validity work perfectly, so the model is working.

I am trying to do this in the model as opposed to the index.  I believe I read last night that Rails 4 prefers (deprecates?) these tests in the code instead of the database, but I cannot find that source tonight. (?)  Either way, I'd like to see the model working.

Comment: Just a quick note, that may not help you for this particular question but could help you for your tests, have a look a shoulda-matchers: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Comment: Looks very interesting and thank you for that.  I'm a bit overloaded on testing methods at the moment, as you can see through this thread.  But, I'll save this in my bag for later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `should_not be_valid` on some object. Try this

```
before(:each) do
  @feed_with_same_url = @feed.dup
  @feed_with_same_url.feed_url = @feed.feed_url
end
it { @feed_with_same_url.should_not be_valid }
```

Comment: This made sense, so I tried it.  I received NoMethodError on Nil.  If you trace the flow, the it is actually executed before the before block, believe it or don't.  So, @feed_with_same_url is nil at that time.  The describe runs through the it's and then executes the before's for each it that it has collected...  At least that is the flow that I have seen.

Comment: Try passing `:each` option to before method call. i have updated my answer

Comment: Okay, that worked.  Blows my mind, but it works.  I showed the create/save methods because I believed those drove the model.  You took out the save and it worked.  I really don't understand.  Could you please elaborate on this?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Note that I get the same result whether or not the :each is specified with before.  before do and before(:each) do gives the same result...

Comment: OK, the first point is using instance variables. If you assign local variables in before block, it will not be available in your test. Secondly to check if an object is valid, you dont need to save it, but it shudnt matter.

Comment: Okay, that works.  Further testing indicates that setting feed_with_same_url.feed_url to a non-duplicate but valid URL fails the test as expected.  Funny, I copied that code from RailsTutorial where it worked...

Answer (score 1):

What is `it` in the context of that test? Without the full code, it's probably not `feed_with_same_url`, so your test is not checking what you think it's checking.

If I was writing this test, it would be something like:

```
let(:feed) { FactoryGirl.create :feed }
let(:feed_with_same_url) { feed.dup }

subject { feed_with_same_url }

it { should_not be_valid }
```

Now `it` is the subject, which is `feed_with_same_url`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the validates are in the model and the rest of the code is a Capybara construct in feed_spec.rb.  I believe this is standard coding.  I am going to work on it to discover whether I can tell what self the it is selecting.

Comment: You're not using Capybara at all, this is a model spec.

Comment: I meant that the original question was poorly formatted.  Question updated to clarify this issue.

Comment: You're still not using Capybara. Can you clarify what part of my answer you don't understand, because your comments don't address my answer at all.

Comment: You are correct.  I use both and just confuse terminology when I switch from one to the other.  The many varied testing methods available are driving me a bit crazy.

Comment: Your answer looks valid as well.